# Getting com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception where all the returned response values from S3 is either null or 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting the below exception while downloading some files from S3. All the returned response values from S3 is either null or 0

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Problem while downloading chunks (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code: null; Request ID: null), S3 Extended Request ID: null
```

What could be the possible reason for this issue? Am unable to track as Status Code returned cannot comply with AWS S3 error list.

Comment: I assume you are downloading the files using aws sdk java. Are you able to download some other files from same bucket successfully? If yes, then there is a possibility that this particular file could be corrupted.

Comment: yes i am able to download other files from the bucket successfully and also using aws sdk java. Only with some files the issue is happening.

Comment: Can you please show your code?